# How to get array from json using ResourceRequest in liferay

Tags: arrays, json, controller, liferay

I have got my json

```
<script type="application/javascript">
var filterDto = {
        page: 2,
        tags: {
            tagArray: ['tag1', 'tag2']
        },
        search: 'b'
    }
;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<%=myUrl%>",
    data: filterDto,
    success: function (msg) {
        console.log('works');
    }
});
```

And here is my controller method on backend

```
@ResourceMapping("myUrl")
public void filterDocuments(ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response)
        throws IOException, SystemException {
    log.info(request);
}
```

I tried to extract `page` and `search` parameter with `PortalUtil` class and it works. But I can't extract my array of tags. I used `ParamUtil.getStringValues()` but it returns me an empty array. How to deal with it?

Comment: What version of the Liferay are you using?

Comment: I don't see `ParamUtil.getStringValues()` in Liferay 6.2! In-fact, there is `ParamUtil.getParameterValues()` which returns `String[]` if request parameter(s) is found.